# Specs for ActiveRecord::Migration helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, migration

I have added `monetize` and `demonetize` helpers inside `ActiveRecord::Migration`, `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition` and `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Table` by [that pull request](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails/pull/56/files).

[That file](https://github.com/FUT/money-rails/blob/e848a054eb16ddc4bd8531db68ca18649f6e709d/spec/dummy/db/migrate/20121123202309_test_monetize_migrations.rb) shows usage examples. So you will understand invented changes at glance. (It works)

But I have no idea how to test my helpers. What way can I write specs for them? All my attempts of writing migrations in spec files and running them manually failed. Migration manual run did not change table (or I was unable to detect changes) and did not throw any exception.

Example of my attempt:

```
describe 'monetize' do
  class MonetizeMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table :items
      monetize :items, :price
    end
  end

  class Item < ActiveRecord::Base; end

  it 'should monetize items' do
    MonetizeMigration.up    #=> nil
    Item                    #=> Item(has no table)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute any migration helper methods right on your database connection:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_table :items
```

Thanks to @happy_user for showing my mistake in first attempt. I think someone may use my latest solution in the future, so I'll leave it here.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in the console:

```
[4667]foo@bar:~/dev/ror/foo$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.9)
irb(main):001:0> class MyMigration   def change
irb(main):003:2>   create_table :foo
irb(main):004:2>  end
irb(main):005:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> MyMigration.new.change
-- create_table(:foo)
   (4.5ms)  select sqlite_version(*)
   (133.2ms)  CREATE TABLE "foo" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL) 
   -> 0.2362s
=> []
```

Comment: hmhm.. I think it was my silly mistake :D anyway I'll check it out on the next week and change that question status. Thanks!